# Exporting function in react js

Tags: reactjs

Kindly check the below code. Generally `export` realates to the component in the module. However, in this program something else seems to be exported: `export default screenHoc(\)(Login);`.
Can anyone please explain how this line is working? Can someone give a clear idea of Exports in React

```js
import React from "react";
import {screenHoc} from "ui-hocs";
import {Div} from "ui-atoms";
import {RenderScreen} from "ui-molecules";

class Login extends React. Component {
  render()
  {
 
    return (
      <Div>
        <Div style = {{ textAlign:"center", color:"#3f51b5"}}>
          <h2>USER LOGIN FORM</h2>
        </Div>
          <RenderScreen
            components={this.props.components}
            uiFramework={this.props.uiFramework}
            onFieldChange={this.props.onFieldChange}
            onComponentClick={this.props.onComponentClick}
          />
      </Div>
    )
  }
}

export default screenHoc({path:"core",screenKey:"login"})(Login);
```

Comment: You forgot to share your code.

Comment: This should help you. https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly mentioned, the `export default` statement is used to export this module's component - `Loign`.
However - in this case the `Login` component is being passed into the `screenHoc` [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) - an advanced React pattern which is usually used to add some additional functionality (or data) to the original component.

So in short - what is returned from this line:

`screenHoc({path:"core",screenKey:"login"})(Login)`

Is an "improved" or "enriched" version of the `Login` component and that is what's being exported from this module.